# How to get absolute path of existing folder

Tags: java

I have a test data folder in my java project... something like this

Project

- src Folder
- testData Folder

How can I get the data folder using java, previously we have a hardcoded the in a constant, but now we are using a CI tool and I want to avoid the hardcoded path.

Answer (score 1):

its is very fine to hardcode the testdata folder, but the
point is that it should be a relative path:

At the top of the test class you can just write

```
static final String TEST_PATH = "./testdata/";
```

Note that this is relative to the project.

If you want to convert such a relative path to an absoulte one:

```
String absoluteTestPath = new File(TEST_PATH).getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the input parameter and create a new File Object. The Java file object will provide getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), and getCanonicalPath(). Be careful with the file systems. If you are swapping between Windows/Linux/Mac/etc, you may have issues with translating paths between source and destination. I assume you source and destination are on the same file system in the example below.

```
File f = new File(pathStr);
String absPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)?

```
Paths.get("your-relative-path-here").toAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my issue in the following way

```
public static final String Path_TestData = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\TestData\\";
```

Comment: why are the testdata dependent on the user dir, tests should normaly be relative to the src path.

Answer (score 0):

For `src`

```
static String SRC_PATH = new File(".").getCanonicalPath()+System.getParameter("file.separator")+SRC;
// where SRC is the name of your source folder
```

For `testdata`:-

```
static String TEST_PATH = "./testdata/";
```